# NodeJS run a script js into a script

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to run a node script into a node script like, my main script is called index.js and the script i want to run is called test.js so, i run my main script on cmd with: node index.js but, i want when i do the command (prefix + "test") it's run my script text in my folder

here is my command:

```
client.on("message", message => 
{
    let cmd = message.content.split(" ")[0] 
    cmd = cmd.slice(prefix.length)
    let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1)

 if (cmd == "test") 
    {
      const testscript = require("./extensions/test.js")
       //code for run it
    }
});
```

thanks in advance !

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is; if you've imported ("required") the file then you have access to whatever it exposes.

Comment: i just want to run test.js while my index.js is running

Comment: Is `test.js` file exporting any functions that you can run? @Randy

Comment: What do you mean by "run test.js"? You can access what is *exposed* by `test.js`, e.g., its `module.exports`, like any other JS code. If you want to pretend you're executing it from the command line that's a different thing--and likely not necessary.

Comment: well, this test.js don't have any things i want to get, i just need to run it with the command node test.js welcome and i want when i do the command test, it's run it with this node test.js welcome

Comment: I would consider restructuring things somewhat. Instead of making `test.js` a CLI, make its functionality *available* to a CLI if you really need it as a CLI, and have that same functionality available to anything else that might want to use it as an "API".

Comment: I see, thanks for your informations

Answer (score 1):

As people have mentioned in the comments, you might want to adjust the way you're doing things. Here's what I suggest

**./extensions/test.js**

```js
exports.yourFunctionNameHere = function(){
  //whatever was previously in test.js
}
```

**Main code**

```js
client.on("message", message => 
{
    let cmd = message.content.split(" ")[0] 
    cmd = cmd.slice(prefix.length)
    let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1)

 if (cmd == "test") 
    {
      const testscript = require("./extensions/test.js")
      testscript()
    }
});
```

Also it looks like you might have some arguments so you can just have those as parameters to the test.js function

Also, in case you were wondering, this is how you execute a command in node:

```js
const childProcess = require('child_process')

childProcess.exec('your command here')
```

If you want to look more into it, see [this](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)